Titles, section headings and captions in title case in Koma-Script?
How to make all headings (title, section headings, table and figure captions etc.) in title case in scrartcl?
Some journals want "Sentence case.", others title "Title Case.", so if I write everything in sentence case to begin with, I would quickly like to change some settings to get everything to title case without the need to change everything manually.
[EDIT]
Captions would work for figures with titlecaps but not for tables, beacause the software I am using places \label{tab:my_label} inside the \caption{}. Apparently placing label inside caption is not a bug but even desirable.
Preferably, I would like to accomplish everything with BibLaTex but as long as it works with Koma script, I am open to anything, as long as it automatas everything (no manual changes needed for e.g. tables).
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=none]{caption}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{titlecaps} % probably cannot use
\Addlcwords{is are to on of into onto unto and or both about above across after against around at beneath beside between beyond but by during except for from in inside into near}


% What I have tried

%1
%\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\titlecap{#1}} %does not Capitalize

%2
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeTitlecase{#1}} %does not Capitalize
%\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{titlecap}{\titlecap{#1}} %does not Capitalize the table caption as it has (\label{tab:my_label} inside)
%\captionsetup{textformat=titlecap,labelsep=quad}


\begin{document} 
    
    \title{\vspace{-3cm} Here the Story begins}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introductory section Starts here}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This is my Figure heading for First figure}
    \end{figure}
    
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
            \hline
            Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
            Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\label{tab:my_label}A simple Table with three Columns and three Rows.}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}


Please also see related posts here and here. Keeping them seperate as they all address slighlty different setup.

Please don't change already answered questions significantly. If you find that your question does not address all aspects of your problem, you should ask a follow-up question instead. And please also note, that the MWE should always show the problem immediately and without the need to change anything like removing some %. So IMHO your question should be reverted to the original one. Your new question, e.g., could be: How to use \label inside \titlecap?

You could, e.g., define a command:
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\MyCaps}[1]{\MakeTitlecase{#1}}
%\DeclareRobustCommand*{\MyCaps}[1]{\titlecap{#1}}
%\DeclareRobustCommand*{\MyCaps}[1]{#1}

Now, you are able to use \MyCaps wherever you want either \MakeTitlecase, \titlecap or no change, depending on the journal. In the following example, I use it for the document title.
Additionally you can use KOMA-Script feature \sectionlinesformat (and \sectioncatchphraseformat if needed) to use \MyCaps automatically:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=none]{caption}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{is are to on of into onto unto and or both about above across after against around at beneath beside between beyond but by during except for from in inside into near}

%\DeclareRobustCommand*{\MyCaps}[1]{\MakeTitlecase{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\MyCaps}[1]{\titlecap{#1}}
%\DeclareRobustCommand*{\MyCaps}[1]{#1}


%\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\titlecap{#1}} %does not Capitalize
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeTitlecase{#1}} %does not Capitalize
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{titlecap}{\titlecap{#1}}
\captionsetup{textformat=titlecap,labelsep=quad}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}\MyCaps{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} % Document starts here
    
    \title{\MyCaps{Here the Story begins}}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introductory section Starts here}

    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is my Figure heading for First figure}
    \end{figure}

    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
            \hline
            Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
            Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A simple Table with three Columns and three Rows.}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}


Note: The “The” in the title is, because you've forgotten to define “the” as lower case word. And IMHO all those exceptions make the whole thing a little bit critical to handle. IMHO it's easier to use \newcommand\MyCaps[1]{#1} and manually do, e.g., \MyCaps{Here the Story Begins}, but use \let\MyCaps\MakeTitlecase if I want only the first letter in upper case. But this is only an opinion.

Addendum for your question edit (which I do not recommend, because it changes the already answered question significant and therefore it would be better to ask a follow-up question instead):
I do not know, how the protect \label{…} automatically from been processed by \titlecap. The easiest IMHO should be to modify your software, which we do not know and therefore makes your question somehow unclear, so move the \label{…} behind \caption{…}. Another guess would be to ask the titlecaps author for a solution. Another suggestion would be to modify your software to use \Label{{…}} instead of \label{…} and then define
\NewDocumentCommand{\Label}{m}{\label{#1}}

Here you can see, that this would work:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=none]{caption}

\usepackage{titlecaps} % probably cannot use
\Addlcwords{is are to on of into onto unto and or both about above across after against around at beneath beside between beyond but by during except for from in inside into near}

\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{titlecap}{\titlecap{#1}}
\captionsetup{textformat=titlecap,labelsep=quad}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Label}{m}{\label{#1}}

\begin{document} 
    
    See also figure~\ref{tab:my_label}.
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This is my Figure heading for First figure}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
            \hline
            Row 1, Col 1 & Row 1, Col 2 & Row 1, Col 3 \\
            Row 2, Col 1 & Row 2, Col 2 & Row 2, Col 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{\Label{{tab:my_label}}A simple Table with three Columns and three Rows.}% Note the replacement of `\label` and the `{{…}}` instead of `{…}` for the argument of `\Label`.
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}

Instead of \Label{{tab:my_label}} you can alternatively use \protect\label{{tab:my_label}}.

titlecaps won't actually work for captions in my real life problem. Have updated the question and MWE. Any way to make capitalization work with \label inside \caption?

@SamuelSaari IMHO this is more a follow-up question or even a bug report to package titlecaps. And IMHO the easiest solution would be to move the \label{…} behind the \caption{…}. \MakeTitlecase in opposite to \titlecap handles \label correctly. \titlecap has a problem, not only with the _ in the label name.
